# Latex Code for a Symbol

Tags: symbols

Could anyone help me in finding the code for the following symbol?
I tried different mathematical formulas or symbols. I could not find it

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer via the following link. You can draw your symbol. It will help you to find the possible matches and the latex code for it

http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html